# Hive query with WHERE clauses doesn't work

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, where-clause

I have two table in Apache hive. The first is called `traffic_violations` and the second is called `cars`.

So, in `traffic_violations` I have a column called `fatl` with values "Yes" or "No". I set this column as a STRING. I make the join between the table with an id.

So, I have this query:

```
select gender, fatal, substr(date_of_stop,7,10) as year, make 
from traffic_violations t 
join cars c on t.id = c.id 
where fatal = "Yes" 
group by date_of_stop, make, gender, fatal
```

If I remove the `WHERE` clause, the query works, but with this clause it does not work.

Hive print this message:

```
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 1809950422 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Stage-Stage-2:  HDFS Read: 797286840 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
OK
Time taken: 31.228 seconds
```

but Hive doesn't print the result of this query.

How do I resolve this problem?

Thanks to all!

Comment: It seems that there are no rows matching WHERE clause.

Comment: Can you please post the sample data.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand

Comment: Edit your question to show us your table schema and the data without the where clause